# How do I authorize a user that was authenticated by an external provider (CAS) if the user's role is stored in a separate external database (.NET 6)?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, authorization, asp.net-identity, roles

I am creating a .NET 6 web app that uses an external authentication provider (CAS). Authentication works fine and I am able to get the authentication state and pull the authenticated username:

```
private async void AuthorizeUser()
{
    var authstate = await GetAuthenticationStateAsync.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();  
    var casUserName = authstate.User.Identity.Name;
}
```

The user roles are stored in an external, non-ASP.NET-Identity database and I use the authenticated username to retrieve the assigned role for the current user (e.g., let's assume the username is "authuser" and the assigned role is "Admin"). This also works fine.

What I would like to do next is to authorize the user based upon this role. I am familiar role-based authorization in .NET Identity but am unclear on the relationship between authentication state and Identity. Can I programmatically add the "Admin" role to authstate.User.Identity and then then use the role-based authorization attributes? If so, how do I add the role?

If this approach will not work, what is the recommended way to programmatically use an externally-derived role in Identity (I would prefer not to use an Identity database in this case)?

Examples will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to use role based authentication without Identity? I think you can try to use JWT , Then add role in claim.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would do it:

1. You can make use of the `IClaimsTransformer` interface in order to capture the User's claims, then add your logic for fetching the User's Role, get the role, and add it as an additional Claim to the Authorization Token. [This is a quick guide on how to achieve this](https://benfoster.io/blog/customising-claims-transformation-in-aspnet-core-identity/)
2. Once your new role claims have been added, you can add a custom Policy that dictates the user requires that role:

   ```cs
   builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
   {
        options.AddPolicy("RequireAdministratorRole",
            policy => policy.RequireClaim(JwtClaimTypes.Role, "Admin"));
   });
   ```
3. Then you can just require that policy in your `Authorize` attribute

   ```cs
    [Authorize(Policy = "RequireAdministratorRole")]
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Foo() {
       // endpoint logic
    }
   ```